# 3 black wires into switch

Tags: switch

I have a simple light switch in a closet and I wanted to change it out for one with a switch and an outlet.  The back of the switch had 3 black wires - 2 going into push in connectors on the top left and bottom right and 1 screwed into the side screw on the top left.

My replacement switch has no plug-ins, just 4 side screws and a ground.

How do I reattach the wires?

Thanks,

Eric

[image: old outlet]

[image: new outlet]

[![old switch
][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ba21.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ba21.jpg)[box with wires](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI4iz.jpg)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI4iz.jpg)

Comment: Does this new switch have a pilot light or such? Can you post a photo of the inside of the box please?

Comment: Also, was the old switch labeled "ON" and "OFF"?

Comment: no pilot light - it is legrand toggle switch / outlet                                                    no on or off labelling - picture I am attaching was the off position .                             pictures are attached to original post

Comment: Was there another switch that controlled this light?

Comment: No, it is a switch in a small closet = not even an outlet, which is why I got into this in the first place.

Comment: First question: do you have a neutral wire in the box? It would probably be white and not connected to the current switch. If that isn’t there, you’re dead in the water. This is required to add an outlet.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: United States of America

Comment: You removed the existing switch from a metal object in the wall of the closet called a _box_. Can you show us a photo of the wiring within that box so that we can ascertain whether you likely have access to the complete set of wires that you need to connect the device that you've displayed in the bottom photo.

Comment: Do you want me to pull the wires out of the box I showed in picture 4?